# Prove that $\frac{1}{f'(a)} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{1}{f(z)-f(a)} dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f$ be analytic on an open set $U$, let $a \in U$, and $f'(a)\neq 0$.

Show that 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{f'(a)} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{1}{f(z)-f(a)} dz
\end{align*}
where $C$ is a small circle centered at a.

I thought that this is very similar with Cauchy's integral formula. But, I can't apply the Cauchy's integral formula. How to apply that?

Any help is appreciated..

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct formula is
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{f'(a)} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{1}{f(z)-f(a)} dz \, ,
\end{align*}
$$
which holds if the interior of $C$ contains no other roots of $f(z) - f(a)$ except $z=a$.

It follows from the Residue theorem: For $z \to a$ we have
$$
 f(z) = f(a) + f'(a)(z-a) + O(z-a)^2 \\
\Longrightarrow
  \frac{1}{f(z)-f(a)} = \frac{1}{f'(a)(z-a)} + O(1) \\
\Longrightarrow
 \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{1}{f(z)-f(a)} dz = \operatorname{Res}(\frac{1}{f(z)-f(a)}, a) = \frac{1}{f'(a)}
$$

Comment: What does O(1) mean?

Comment: @Sophia: That is the [“Big O Notation”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Here is denotes a quantity which is *bounded* near $z=a$.

Answer (score 2):

It can be viewed as [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) applied to the inverse of $f$.

Since $f'(a)\ne0$, the [Inverse Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Holomorphic_Functions) says that there is an analytic $g$, defined in a neighborhood of $f(a)$, so that
$$
f(g(z))=z\tag1
$$
Taking the derivative of $(1)$ gives
$$
f'(g(z))g'(z)=1\tag2
$$
Equation $(1)$
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac1{f(z)-f(a)}\mathrm{d}z
&=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|g(z)|=r}\frac{g'(z)}{z-f(a)}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag3\\
&=g'(f(a))\tag4\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{f'(a)}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(3)$: substitute $z\mapsto g(z)$
$(4)$: Cauchy's Integral Formula
$(5)$: apply $(2)$ at $z=f(a)$

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think this equation is not generally true.

Consider $f(z)=z^2$ and take $a=8$, then:

$$R.H.S.=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{1}{z^2-16}dz=0$$ since  $\frac{1}{z^2-16}$ is holomorphic in the neighborhood of $8$.

While $L.H.S.=\frac{1}{16}\ne R.H.S.$.

Comment: There was a typo in the question originally. Since $f(a)=64$, not $16$, this does not seem to be a counterexample any more.

Answer (score 0):

The equation holds iff $a$ is the **only simple root** of $f(z)=0$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_C \frac{1}{f(z)-f(a)} d z = & \frac{1}{2 \pi i} 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}\left[\frac{1}{f(z)-f(a)}, a\right] \\
= & \lim _{z \rightarrow a} \frac{z-a}{f(z)-f(a)}\\=& \frac 1{\lim _{z \rightarrow a} \frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}}\\=&\frac{1}{f^{\prime}(a)}
\end{aligned}
$$